# How to get XPath if subject is hidden with javascript

Tags: xpath

Here is a link

https://www.dscbalances.com/ohaus-mb23-moisture-analyzer.html

I need to get Xpath for price that in popup of `'See Price in Cart'` under crossed price.

```
//*[@id="product-price-3395_clone"]/span
```

doesn't work

Comment: XPath is correct. Do you use something like Selenium to extract the value? Share the code you use

Comment: @Andersson I need to use it in google spreadsheet with function IMPORTXML